# Plotting a Linear GAM (Generalized Additive Model) from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, gam

I found this example code but am having trouble isolating it to a single Y and X without the 'for loop'.

I keep getting this TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable.

Example Code: https://pygam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/tour_of_pygam.html#Regression

Desired Dataframey = Continuous VariableX = Continuous VariableLegend/Coloring = Text/Factor Variable

```py
from pygam import LinearGAM, s, f
from pygam.datasets import wage

X, y = wage(return_X_y=True)

## model
gam = LinearGAM(s(0) + s(1) + f(2))
gam.gridsearch(X, y)


## plotting
plt.figure();
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3);

titles = ['year', 'age', 'education']
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
  XX = gam.generate_X_grid(term=i)
  ax.plot(XX[:, i], gam.partial_dependence(term=i, X=XX))
  ax.plot(XX[:, i], gam.partial_dependence(term=i, X=XX, width=.95)[1], c='r', ls='--')
  if i == 0:
      ax.set_ylim(-30,30)
  ax.set_title(titles[i]);
```

Here's what I want the end result to look like:

[image]

Please let me know if you have any more questions.

I tried removing the for loop and adjusting the subplot attribute to plt.subplot(1,1) instead of (1,3)

I keep getting this TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable.

Comment: Are you saying you want a single plot for 'year', a single plot for 'age', and a single plot for 'education', instead of all these three plotted together?

Comment: In other words, you want to translate ggplot code into matplotlib code. I suggest this article to help you: https://towardsdatascience.com/plotting-the-same-chart-with-matplotlib-and-ggplot2-7261dc9e0e7b